# How to apply a Typescript Generic to the following API fetcher

Tags: typescript

I've created a fair simple function to wrap around fetch. What i'm trying to figure out is how i can use TS Generics to set the Type for 'data' in the return.

```
const apiFetchData = async (
    url: string,
    options = {},
): Promise<FetchResponse> => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const data = (await res.json()) || null;
        const statusCode = res.status;

        return {
            data,
            hasData: !!data,
            statusCode,
            error: (statusCode !== 200 && true) || false,
            errorType: (statusCode !== 200 && 'api') || null,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            data: {
                error: error.message,
            },
            hasData: false,
            statusCode: 500,
            error: true,
            errorType: 'application',
        };
    }
};
```

The FetchResponse type looks like this:

```
type FetchResponse = {
  data: {
    [key: string]: {};
    error?: string;
  };
  hasData: boolean;
  statusCode: number;
  error: boolean | null;
  errorType?: 'api' | 'application' | null;
};
```

If i know my API will return the following:

```
type User = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
```

Then i somehow want my FetchResponse to be:

```
type FetchResponse = {
  data: User;
  hasData: boolean;
  statusCode: number;
  error: boolean | null;
  errorType?: 'api' | 'application' | null;
};
```

That way i can then do something like this:

```
const response = await apiFetchData('URL');
console.log('User name is', response.data.name);
```

Currently i do something like this, which works, but it seems LOOOOONG

```
type FetchWithUserType = FetchResponse & {
    data: {
        error?: string;
        user?: User;
    };
};
```

and then:

```
const response: FetchWithUserType = await apiFetchData('URL');
console.log('User name is', response.data.name);
```

If generics isnt the way forward, can someone help me make this better so i can do what i'm after. Essentially the problem is that i want my VSCode intellisense to know what is within the data returned. Vs. being an  and having to keep switching between code.

Comment: I eould suggest two improvements: first, make union out of FetchResponse: SuccessfulResponse and ErrorResponse. Secondly, make SuccessfulResponse generic

Comment: you would need to set a generic on both the definition of the apiFetchData function as well as the `FetchResponse` type and you would make the type for the data entry something like `T  & { error?: string} `. I haven't been able to test this, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you mean when you say "I know my API will return the following".  I assume you don't mean your API will *always* return that or you would have just defined FetchResponse to include that data.

If you mean, that you know the API will return the structure for a certain URL, you could handle that with generics as follows:

```
async function apiFetchData<T extends {[key:string]: any}>(
// function params omitted
):Promise<FetchResponse<T>> => {
// function code omitted
}
```

And then define FetchResponse as

```
type FetchResponse<S> = {
   data: <S>
   // rest of the type
}
```

Basically you are using the generic to tell TS that you know what the form of the data will be so it can insert it into the FetchResponse type.

If you mean that you don't know what the API will return in advance, but it might return data in the format User, then you will need to use a type guard.  But I think you probably mean something like the previous example.

Comment: This is my take on the question, too. Seems like OP is looking for `type X<A> = { data: A }`

Comment: Yes, my Fetch calls my internal API. So i KNOW that there will be Data, bvut each endpoint might return different data. So i just need the data part of the respone to be 'typed' differently. I'll have a look at what you've suggested, looks like what i need though. Thanks for this! (edit: removed something that could be seen as rude, which was not my intent, so to avoid confusion removed it)